# PhpStorm ctrl+w granularity

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I think in previous versions of PHP storm ctrl+w shortcut was more granular,  in previous versions it selects first wrapped content and in then the brackets, how can I set its granularity in consecutive presses?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, this is exactly how it works:

http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html

How is your different?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to adjust granularity of selection. If you don't like the current behavior in some particular situation feel free to create a Feature Request/Usability problem at: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/